# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Customer

Tags: php, class

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Customer
```

Then I added the following code:

```
if (!class_exists('Customer')) {
    include('include/customer.class.php');
}
```

Why do I still get that error?

I have a file (file1.php) which has the Customer() class declared.

In file1.php I make an ajax call to file2.php

In file2.php I declare the Customer() class again.

In file2.php there is only 1 declaration of Customer() class.

Comment: do you include 'include/customer.class.php' anywhere else?

Comment: Do you have a class named `Customer` declared elsewhere? That's the only way this would make sense.

Comment: Yes, that's why I added if (!class_exists('Customer'))

Comment: @php I mean, do you have a class named `Customer` declared in some other file already?

Comment: @php Do you have a class named `Customer` delared in some **other** file already?

Comment: Did you added that code (`class_exists()` one) everywhere? both in file1.php and file2.php?

Answer (score 5):

Check if your server runs opcode cacher like APC - that's the cause of an error. I've runned into it recently.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly due to the fact I issue:

```
if (!class_exists('Customer')) {
```

The class doesn't exist so the class itself is somehow duplicating itself.

I use this class in numerous other pages in the application without a problem.

I simply removed the whole thing:

```
if (!class_exists('Customer')) {
  include('include/customer.class.php');
}
```

And it somehow worked which is preplexing!

1. If the class existed, the class file should never be included...
2. It doesn't exist therefore, the class is being included.
3. Once included, it says it's already included...

Very, very odd...

Well, it's working now... I guess i'll leave it be...

Answer (score 0):

Use include_once(). If that still gives you an error, the problem is that you are declaring the class more than once in the file "include/customer.class.php"

http://php.net/include_once

Comment: This will hardly solve the problem, because `class_exists()` should already be preventing double inclusion. The problem must be elsewhere in the OP's code.

Comment: The problem is kind of obvious, he is declaring the class Customer more than once in the file "include/customer.class.php", he may be including another file or whatever there.

Using include_once will not only prevent future problems like this, but also show us where if the problem is the class_exists function or his include file

Comment: @Ivan the problem is more likely that he is declaring a class named `Customer` *somewhere else*, which is something `include_once` won't protect against.

Comment: He didn't tell us which line is causing the problem so we suppose it's this line `include('include/customer.class.php');` which will only get executed if the class Customer is not defined _yet_.

If that line is causing the error, the possible problems are:
- PHP class_exists function doesn't work properly (I highly doubt)
- He is declaring the class Customer more than once in the file include/customer.class.php

Using include_once will confirm that the function class_exists was working correctly and that the problem is his include file.

Comment: @php-b-grader which file is causing the error? file1 or file2?

Comment: I've been using customer.class.php in many other files...  It's odd that it is causing this now I've added it to another file... The only thing that is unusual about its usage this time is that I'm calling the page using AJAX ... I've removed it and it appears to be working but I don't understand where it's being decalred??? Does AJAx pass all the page declarations through???

Comment: The error refers to line 3 of customer.class.php: `class Customer {`

Comment: How are you loading it with Ajax?

It shouldn't be causing that error as is just as if the client visited that page.
Does that error appear if you go to file2.php directly?

Comment: Interesting - calling the file directly also produces this error... Clearly the class is being defined prior in this file and I can't see it...

Comment: a search of file2.php only finds this reference!  I have no idea how this could be happening...

Comment: Are you including other files? Those files may be the ones causing the error as they could be including the class file too.

Answer (score 0):

The errors could be caused by a class defined multiple times, for example:

```
class Foo() {}
class Foo() {} // Fatal error
```

If you are not sure how many times your class will be included you can two things:

1. Use `include_once()` or `require_once()` in order to be sure that that file is required "once" only.
2. Write that code you provided every time you are including that file:

   ```
   if (!class_exists('Customer')) {
       include('include/customer.class.php');
   }
   ```

I'd prefer the first though.
Your problem is the one described above. There must be a place where the class is declared multiple times. Without any code is hard to tell where.

Here's some references:

- [include_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)
- [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)
- [PHP: The Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)